# Cannot turn on trackpad

Tags: trackpad

My laptop (an Aorus x3 plus) has a hardware keyboard combo to turn the trackpad on and off (FN + F10). Since I reinstalled 14.04 this combination does not activate my touchpad, which usefully appears disabled by default in Ubuntu meaning the device is not detected at all.

The keyboard combo works in Windows and the trackpad has worked previously in 14.04.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Same problem here. I opened a bug report on [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1387865), but any answer would be welcome.